# Perl CGI Changes Not Being Reflected in Browser

Tags: perl, debugging, cgi, forms

I am new to Perl Scripts and I am having a bit of trouble.  I have an HTML Form that transmits some data to a CGI script.  However, it seems to be going off the oldest version of the CGI script instead of the newest version.  Is it possibly because there is an error in perl script, which is below? I tried to use the debugger but I could not figure out how to use it to execute my script let alone pass the argument I need to it from the command line. 
Thanks for any help!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
$q = new CGI;

print $q->header;
    $q->start_html('Finger User');
    $q->h1('Finger User');
print "<pre>";

$user = $q->param("user");
print `/usr/bin/finger/ -s $user~`;

print "</pre>";
print $q->end_html;
```

Comment: Run your script in the command line and see what happens.

Comment: yea, I guess, I wasn't clear that's what I tried to do but I couldn't do that because I can't pass the user argument to it.

Comment: @tpar44: Yes you can, see http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#DEBUGGING

Comment: Ps. Since you don't validate the `user` parameter, your script has a **huge** security hole.  (Think about what happens if I pass in the "username" `nobody; rm -rf .;`.)  I'd suggest allowing only usernames matching `/^[a-z][-a-z0-9]*$/i`.  (Regexp copied from [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/73084/what-characters-should-i-use-or-not-use-in-usernames-on-linux).)

Comment: yea thats the point the book I got the script from is making.  I wanted to play around with it though so that I could make it more secure instead of taking their word for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ';' in these lines to ',':

```
print $q->header,
    $q->start_html('Finger User'),
    $q->h1('Finger User');
```

and lose the '/' at the end of

```
/usr/bin/finger
```

Comment: thanks that worked, do you happen to know why it is not working from the browser? It works from the command line but not from the browser.  it still reverts to the older version even with the changes made.

Comment: Why the changes don't show up in the browser? Dunno, depends on the server you're using, but could also be a caching-problem...